# Executing Native Query within JPA Repository Rest Resource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, spring-data-jpa

I am having an issue getting passing a custom query with two parameters to Spring my Spring RepositoryRestResource interface list:

```
    @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "benefitplan", path = "benefitplan")
public interface BenefitPlanRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<BenefitPlan, Long> {
    BenefitPlan findTop1ByBenefitPackageCode(@Param("bpcode") String benefitPackageCode);
    BenefitPlan findByBenefitPackageCode(@Param("bpcode") String benefitPackageCode);
    BenefitPlan findTop1ByBenefitPackageCodeAndPlanStatus(@Param("bpcode") String benefitPackageCode, @Param("status") String status);
    @Query(value = 
            "SELECT b.BENEFIT_PLAN_ID FROM BENEFIT_PLAN b left join MEDICAL_PLAN m on b.MEDICAL_PLAN_ID = m.MEDICAL_PLAN_ID "
            + "left join RX_PLAN r on b.RX_PLAN_ID = r.RX_PLAN_ID WHERE r.MTV_RX_CD = ?2 and m.MTV_MEDICAL_CD = ?1"
            , nativeQuery = true)
    BenefitPlan findByMedicalPlanIdAndRxPlanId(@Param("medicalPlanId") String medicalPlanId, @Param("rxPlanId") String rxPlanId);
}
```

Its The last query, findByMedicalPlanIdAndPlanId that are giving me a problem.  The rest work fine. My error is this:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). could not execute query; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query

Comment: You can rename that method name

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Query(value = 
            "SELECT b.BENEFIT_PLAN_ID FROM BENEFIT_PLAN b left join MEDICAL_PLAN m on b.MEDICAL_PLAN_ID = m.MEDICAL_PLAN_ID "
            + "left join RX_PLAN r on b.RX_PLAN_ID = r.RX_PLAN_ID WHERE r.MTV_RX_CD = :rxPlanId and m.MTV_MEDICAL_CD = :medicalPlanId"
            , nativeQuery = true)
    BenefitPlan findByMedicalPlanIdAndRxPlanId(@Param("medicalPlanId") String medicalPlanId, @Param("rxPlanId") String rxPlanId);
```

If you are using `@Param`, you are expecting to use named parameter, at lease you should do it in the query. if it doesn't work, i suggest you to execute the query in db client to make sure it works.